# ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI dropping on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, routes

Good day, I am in a bit of a problem with my hosted ASP.NET WebAPI and MVC app hosted on IIS on a web server (MS Windows Server 2016). This is a basic website and includes an API in the same project. The web app has Areas and I suspect this is the problem. Periodically the website (Areas and API) goes down, the weird thing is that the views not under areas work fine, and the ones under areas and API stop working. There is no customization from the boiler template code for creating areas and so forth. I have also profiled requests coming in, but these are all basic calls with not a lot of data. I cannot see anything in the Event Viewer or IIS Logs, please does anyone have a suggestions?

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);//WEB API Registration
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        DiConfig.Register();
        
        //Enable Claims Anti Forgery
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
                   
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;

    }
```

Routing Config:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
            
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Exports", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces:new[] {""}
            );
        }
    }
```

WebAPIConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            //config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidationHandler());

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            //Configure to use XmlSerializer so you don't have to configure namespace in xml request
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<CertificateRequest>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(CertificateRequest)));
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
            //Ignore Self Looping References
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            //WEB API Throttling
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ThrottlingHandler()
            {
                Policy = ThrottlePolicy.FromStore(new PolicyConfigurationProvider()),
                Repository = new CacheRepository()
            });
            //
            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `the ones under areas and API stop working` What do you mean stop working? Is there any more error message? Can you show the not working page?

Comment: It is basically the normal yellow page when it cannot find a view. I will attached the image.